# biginteger on Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, biginteger

Can anyone provide code for a [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) implementation in objective-c that provides a PowMod function ?

Answer (score 10):

I hope it's not too late to answer this thread.

You can try "[LibTomMath](http://www.libtom.net)" which is opensource and free (the author give away this project as public domain). It works out of the box without any configuration, just put all bn_*.c and tommath*.h to your Xcode project and you are ready to go.

```
#import "tommath.h"

mp_int number1, number2, number3;

mp_init(&number1);
mp_init(&number2);
mp_init(&number3);

mp_read_radix(&number1, "0a120edfff558c98a73015d5d67e8990", 16);
mp_read_radix(&number2, "12e6f45d698c7b7009a841c1348d6ff4", 16);

mp_mul(&number1, &number2, &number3);

char output[1000];
mp_toradix(&number3, output, 16);
NSLog(@"number3:%s", output);

mp_div(&number3, &number1, &number2, NULL);
mp_toradix(&number2, output, 16);
NSLog(@"number2:%s", output);
```

Comment: TomMath doesn't appear to have a pow() function, it can square or square root, but if you want to raise to the power of n it isn't simple.

Comment: Of course it has exponentiation — the function is called `mp_expt_d`.

Answer (score 7):

As plain C library, openssl's [BN](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/bn.html) should be able to do it.

> `BN_mod_exp()` computes a to the p-th power modulo m (r=a^p % m). This function uses less time and space than BN_exp().

Answer (score 7):

You can try https://github.com/kirsteins/JKBigInteger It is similar to Java's [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class. It has mod and pow methods that you can combine.

Comment: Works perfectly! Great Third part library!

Comment: It seems, that internally "LibTomMath" is used (see iwat's answer).

Answer (score 4):

The closest builtin class in the Cocoa libraries is [`NSDecimalNumber`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which provides base-10 arithmetic (and so can handle integer-only arithmetic) for the range mantissa x 10^exponent where mantissa is a 38-bit float and exponent is -128 to 128. If that covers the range you need, there are multiplication and power methods. Otherwise, since Objective-C is a superset of C, any C implementation of bigint that you can find will suffice.

Comment: This is almost certainly not what the author is looking for.  `NSDecimalNumber` uses a base-10 numbering system to encode and manipulate numbers, not the (much) more common base-2.  A base-10 number system is typically used whenever currency is involved.  In fact, it may be unlawful to process currency related numbers in a non-base-10 numbering systems, depending on your jurisdiction.

Answer (score 2):

I rolled my own wrapper around GMP once, long ago.  I've never used any third party BigNum ObjC librariers before, but I had these bookmarked: [RSMath](http://code.google.com/p/rsmath/), which uses the OpenSSL bignum functions, and [MPInteger](http://code.google.com/p/mpinteger/), which uses GMP.