# BigInteger in objective c

Tags: objective-c, arbitrary-precision

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [biginteger on Objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226949/biginteger-on-objective-c)

Is there any NS* class for arbitrary size integers in objective c like BigInteger in C#? if not, is gmp a good library to import or is there a better library/way? The operations I need is addition, subtraction, multiplication and division(with truncation). Memory is a big issue for this application so the one that uses least memory will be the best. Run time is not an issue as long as it doesn't take years per operation.

Comment: its not because I don't need PowMod and I need one with low memory use

Comment: Try the suggestions from the dupe and profile them for memory usage.