# How to exponentiate really large numbers in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, math

I'm having some trouble calculating the result of an 8-digit number to the power of a 3-digit number programmatically in Objective-C.

Take these numbers, for instance: `16468920^258`, which should result in a number that is [1862 digits in length](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=16468920%5E258).

I naïvely tried:

```
unsigned long long result = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 258; i++)
    result *= 16468920;
```

…but `result` outputs `0`.

Then I tried:

```
long double result = powl(16468920, 258);
```

…but `result` outputs `inf`.

After [finding out about NSDecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6715837/2469565), I tried this:

```
NSDecimal result;
NSDecimal number = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"16468920"] decimalValue];
NSDecimalPower(&result, &number, 258, NSRoundPlain);
```

…but `result` outputs `NaN`, so I tried:

```
NSDecimalNumber *number = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithInt:16468920];
NSDecimalNumber *result = [number decimalNumberByRaisingToPower:258];
```

…but this code raises an `NSDecimalNumberOverflowException`.

Any pointers as to which direction I should be going?

Comment: You are going to have to use one of the libraries mentioned here -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic because to store that number as a plain binary number would mean God only knows how many bits

Comment: You need to think about what you can possibly do with this number once you get it.  (Roughly 5610 bits, BTW, or 701 bytes.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Objective-C is a superset of C, you can use a C library such a [BN](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/bn.html):

```
int BN_exp(BIGNUM *r, BIGNUM *a, BIGNUM *p, BN_CTX *ctx);

BN_exp() raises a to the p-th power and places the result in r ("r=a^p"). This
function is faster than repeated applications of BN_mul().
```

See, for example, [here](https://github.com/st3fan/ios-openssl) for how to get openssl into iOS.

Comment: Perfect! This seems to have done the trick! I used the port of [OpenSSL for iOS](https://github.com/st3fan/ios-openssl) along with this [Wrapper for OpenSSL's BigNumber math functions](https://github.com/davedelong/CHMath) to output the result as an `NSString`!

Answer (score 0):

You get that issue because your result still bigger that `NSDecimalNumber` could store.

I recommend you to could use [JKBigInteger](https://github.com/kirsteins/JKBigInteger) instead, it is a Objective-C wrapper around LibTomMath C library. And really easy to use and understand.

Hope this could help.