# Multiply or divide numbers larger than 38 digits in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, math, nsdecimalnumber

I am writing an app  that , among other things will be able to multiply or divide very large numbers by number 19  - Those large numbers could possibly span hundreds of digits . Do you know of a library I could use for that? Thanks in advance. I have tried using NSDecimalNumber but its not able to produce results past 38 digits.

Comment: might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226949/biginteger-on-objective-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If licensing is not an issue [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) is good.

Comment: How do I multiply lets say 102343345345345453453544350 with 0.025 using GMP. I am able to divide and multiply whole numbers but having trouble with multiplying fractional points.

Comment: You can A) Use MPFR for floating point http://www.mpfr.org/. MPFR uses GMP so it will not have been a waste to have it set up. B) Use fractions